# flask-SQLAlchemy create_all() doesn't create tables if called immediately after drop_all

Tags: mysql, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm trying to write `pytest` fixture `app` that create all tables before test and drop all of them after finishing it.

```
@pytest.fixture
def app(request):
    """Create and configure a new app instance for each test."""
    app = create_app("test")  # factory function that return Flask app
    from academy.models import (User, Auth)
    def finalizer():
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        print("tables after drop_all: ",  db.engine.table_names()) # empty list

    request.addfinalizer(finalizer)
    db.create_all()
    print("tables after create_all: ",  db.engine.table_names()) # <<< Error here
    return app
```

by this `app` fixture I got the following output:

```
tables after create_all:  ['user', 'auth']
tables after drop_all:  []
tables after create_all:  []
tables after drop_all:  []
tables after create_all:  []
```

No problem will occur if I ran a single test, But with multiple tests only the first one will run as expected & the remaining will fail.

I wonder why `flask-sqlalchemy` can't create tables after dropping it !

Comment: What is `catalog.db`? I think you need to include more code here.

Comment: `catalog.db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. catalog is just a container object to reuse the same instanses and to avoid circular imports. I removed this misleadibg name.

Comment: Are you starting a new database session before the call? `db.session.remove()` closes the session!

Comment: `create_app()` includes call of `SQLAlchemy(app)`, which should creates new session As I understand.